# Did I translate this correctly?

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm sorry, I just need an extra set of eyes, I'm second guessing myself. I'm working on translating from classic vb6 to c# and I've looked up the table on operator precedence however I'm still not working out correctly.

VB6

```
= _
        m_curAmountInvested * (1 + m_dblInterestRate / 12) ^ m_intMonthsToAttain + _
        m_curAddDeposits * ((1 + m_dblInterestRate / 12) ^ m_intMonthsToAttain - 1) / (m_dblInterestRate / 12)
```

C#

```
= (currentAmountSaved * Math.Pow((1d + interestRate) / 12d, numberOfMonths)) +
                    ((monthlySavingsAmount * (Math.Pow((1d + interestRate) / 12d, numberOfMonths) - 1d)) / (interestRate / 12d))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you may have a problem in your C# code here:

```
Math.Pow((1d + interestRate) / 12d, ...)
```

Your VB6 code has:

```
(1 + m_dblInterestRate / 12) ^ ...
```

vb6 has a higher precedence for the * and / operators than the + and -, so the division will occur before the add.  However, this is not true in the C# version because of the parentheses (i.e., the addition will come first, then the division).

Comment: ahhhh that would be the problem! many thanks, its been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts I'm not clear on:

- The precedence of the exponent operator (^).
- VB6 does some rounding automatically

Otherwise it looks okay, assuming your variable names line up.

You might want to actually *test* both version with a few values and makes sure they come out the same.  And if they're different, check that better rounding hasn't made your C# code isn't actually *more* correct.

**Update:**
A quick check of [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893(VS.80).aspx) gives ^ the *highest* precendence.  However, that's VB.Net.  I couldn't find the docs for vb6, but [StackOverflow agrees with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206/what-is-the-operator-precedence-order-in-vb6), and so I think you're okay in that department as well.

Comment: Exponentation has higher precedence over multiplication, in all languages where it is an infix operator, I believe.

Comment: The section on operator precedence seems to have been dropped from the online MSDN VB6 docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 + m_dblInterestRate / 12 != (1d + interestRate) / 12d
```

binary sum has lower procedence than division. I think you are confusing it with the unary `+` operator (`+5 == 5`) which has higher procedence than division.

Answer (score 0):

First factor in VB is m_curAmountInvested and in C# it is currentAmountSaved. That could be wrong.

Comment: It looks like the OP generally took out pseudo-Hungarian-notation encodings in the variable name, so I would guess that it is intentional.

Comment: I meant Invested vs Saved not Hungarian vs not :)