# is And Operator always evaluated before Or

Tags: vb6, operators

I came across a bug in some VB6 code this morning which wasn't evaluating correctly. The code is in the following format:

```
<Boolean Value 1> Or <Boolean Value 2> And <Boolean Value 3>
```

The fix (in this case) was to put parentheses in as follows:

```
(<Boolean Value 1> Or <Boolean Value 2>) And <Boolean Value 3>
```

Because the `And` was being incorrectly evaluated first so my question is - Is this always the case?

I assume that things like + - * are evaluated using the [BIDMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) rule but what about these operators `And Or Not XOr Is <>` etc

Comment: See this previous answer... [What is the operator precedence order in VB6?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206/what-is-the-operator-precedence-order-in-vb6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Precedence in order of appearance:

```
Negation (Not)

Conjunction (And, AndAlso)

Inclusive disjunction (Or, OrElse)

Exclusive disjunction (Xor)
```

Comment: Note that the short-circuit operators `AndAlso` and `OrElse` are not available in VB6 yet.

Comment: @Stacktracer - not available in VB6 **yet** - when do they plan to introduce them? I have been waiting for Visual Studio 6 Service Pack 7 for **ages**

Comment: It's more likely to be in VB (Classic) 7.0, which would have to be called something else since "VB7" was stolen by VB.Net already.  Maybe once the Windows Team gets the .Net johnnies tossed out of Microsoft entirely (remember the Longhorn fiasco and the changes in Win8 that are coming)?  Let's say "don't hold your breath" though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like in most programming languages, `and` is binding stronger than `or`, so the brackets are necessary in this case.

What also might be interesting is that VB6 has no short-circuit operations, meaning that if you have `if isNumeric(var) and myFunc(var) then ...` myFunc is even executed in case your var is not numeric! This has implications on performance and correctness.

Comment: True, And is sort of "boolean multiply" and Or "boolean add" so it makes sense.