# Multiple Boolean statements VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having issues with some Boolean logic.

Essentially I want something to program in VBA a filter such that,

```
A = True AND (B = True OR B = False)
```

I just cannot seem to get the coding right to do this in VBA (I am using MS Access).

I have tried:

```
A = True AND B = True OR B = False
```

But this obviously fails (looks for either A,B = True OR B = False, essentially).

Am I missing something obvious here?

I chose to left out the actual code, but if requested I can post. My thinking is that I am missing some basic with the Boolean logic.

Comment: Isn't `A = True AND (B = True OR B = False)` equivalent to `A = True`?

Comment: If you want the `()` then put them in.  There is nothing wrong with including them, they do what you want.

Comment: @ScottCraner Oof. Yep. I initially was putting the bracket after the ", resulting in an error. Worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `A`, `B`, and `C` are `Boolean` expressions, then comparing them to a Boolean literal (`True`, `False`) is redundant: the expression is *already* a Boolean expression.

That makes the original logic go like this:

```
If A And (B Or Not C) Then
```

The `And` operator [has greater priority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55215/1188513) than the `Or` operator, so it gets evaluated first; if the `(B Or Not C)` part needs to be evaluated as a whole, then the parentheses are required, otherwise `A And B` takes precedence, making the expression (wrongly) evaluate as:

```
If (A And B) Or Not C ' redundant parentheses to illustrate operator precedence
```

---

Edit: I misread the OP, my brain put that `C` in there. `If A And (B Or Not B) Then` is redundant, [as BigBen pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174554/multiple-boolean-statements-vba/58174735#comment102729885_58174554) - the simplified logic would be `If A Then`. Still worth noting operator precedence and using parentheses when applicable and appropriate though.